# how to submit answer and check if answer is same with the answer in database table php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
$answers = ambilJawabanUSER($simpanID,$conn); // function to save the answer from database table
$userAnswer = $_POST['answers'];

foreach( $userAnswer as $getAnswer ) {
   if ($userAnswer == $answers){
      echo "correct";
else{
echo "wrong";
}
}
```

my code is similar with the code above but it didnt work in my case. anyone has the solution?

Comment: _anyone has the solution?_ Solution for what problem?

Comment: how to submit answer and check if answer is same with the answer in database table php mysql?@B001

Comment: _...how to submit answer and check..._ Huh? You are just repeating what is in the title...Please **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one error in code. Your should try this code

```
$answers = ambilJawabanUSER($simpanID,$conn); // function to save the answer from database table
$userAnswer = $_POST['answers'];

foreach( $answers as $getAnswer ) {
   if ($userAnswer == $getAnswer){
      echo "correct";
}else{
echo "wrong";
}
}
```